# Proper way to extend a Backbone Object using Require JS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am using requireJS in combination with backbone:

```
define([

        "jquery",
        "underscore",
        "backbone",
        "models/modelA"

        ], function( $, _, Backbone, MyModel ) {

        var viewA = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                 this.model = new MyModel();
            }
        });

        return viewA;

});
```

I want to create a new View module, ViewB, that has all of the same methods as viewA, but that uses a  different model in place of modelA.  I know I can override the initialize function, but I am wondering if there is a more concise way, to avoid duplication of code...

```
    define([

        "jquery",
        "underscore",
        "backbone",
        "views/viewA",
        "models/modelB"

        ], function( $, _, Backbone, ViewA, myModel ) {

        var viewB = ViewA.extend({
                initialize: function() {
                     this.model = new MyModel();
                }
        });

        return viewB;

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two views are exactly the same, just pass in the instantiated model instead of creating it in initialize.  Then you only need to define one view.

```
define([

        "jquery",
        "underscore",
        "backbone"
        // no model module needed here.

        ], function( $, _, Backbone ) {

        var viewA = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function() {
            }
        });

        return viewA;

});
```

Then in some other module which `require`s both models and the view:

```
var modelA = new ModelA();
var modelB = new ModelB();
// create 2 instances of ViewA with different model passed in
var viewA = new ViewA({model: modelA});
var viewB = new ViewA({model: modelB});
```

When created like this, each view will have `this.model` set to the instance you pass in.

Answer (score 1):

```
define(['views/ViewA'], function() {
    var ViewA = require('views/ViewA'), // require ViewA
    ViewB = ViewA.extend({
        // add all your ViewB specific methods/properties here
    });

    return ViewB; // return ViewB from the RequireJS module so it can be used elsewhere
});
```

Comment: Any reason not to just `require(['views/ViewA'], function (ViewA) { ...` instead of `define`ing and making the extra `require` call?

Comment: If you're defining modules, yes. `require()` runs code directly whereas what you want to do is define a module, that can then be run later: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define

Comment: Ok tried to paste example, can't in a comment box. See here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config (second example).

Comment: Right, although the difference seems more semantic in this case than anything since there's a hard dependency on `ViewA`. My suggestion [could apply to `define()` as well](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep). I was mainly just wondering about the second `require()` call vs. just passing the dependent view as an argument to the `define()` callback, and if you were doing it for optimization reasons or something.

Comment: *(also, side note - to format code in comments you can wrap it in backticks: ``)*

Comment: I'm not sure I follow -- what I would like is to extend ViewA with a different Model.  I added a broken example above that will hopefully make it more clear what I want to accomplish

Comment: @user1031947 - Pretty much do what GTF suggested, and just override your `initialize` function in the object passed to `extend`.

Comment: @Rob - I was hoping not to have to explicitly override the initialize function, as the code is no different, so would just be repeated.  Is there any other way?

Comment: @RobHruska the extra require() call just clarifies the function arguments (in this case unnecessary, but if you have a lot of dependencies then it's quite useful).